# How to get String Array from cursor

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor, android-arrayadapter

i want convert data from corsor to String [] array
for i can change this static class to dynamic
i want use my cols in place of imageResIds  and imageTitles 
that it s the static class

```
public class StaticImageData {
    private static ImageItem[] mImageItemArray;

    private static int[] imageResIds = {R.drawable.android,
        R.drawable.hamburger, R.drawable.globe, R.drawable.notepad,
        R.drawable.play, R.drawable.sun, R.drawable.tux, R.drawable.yawn};
    private static String[] imageTitles = {"Android", "Burger", "Globe",
        "Note Pad", "Play", "Sun", "Tux", "Yahh!"};

    /**
     * Default image to show
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_INDEX = 0;

    /**
     * @return static instance of the image item array
     */
    public static ImageItem[] getImageItemArrayInstance() {
        if (mImageItemArray == null) {
            mImageItemArray = new ImageItem[imageResIds.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < mImageItemArray.length; i++) {
                ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem(imageTitles[i], imageResIds[i]);
                mImageItemArray[i] = imageItem;
            }
        }
        return mImageItemArray;
    }



}
```

that it s the getall() from my db

```
public  VerbItem[] getAllVerbs() {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = MyDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    ArrayList<VerbItem> myverbs = new ArrayList<VerbItem>();
    try {
        cursor = db.query(MyTables.TABLE_VERBS,
                          VerbsQuery.PROJECTION,
                          null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                VerbItem page = new VerbItem(
                                     cursor.getInt(VerbsQuery.TAG_ID_VERB_COL),
                                     cursor.getInt(VerbsQuery.TAG_ID_PAGE_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_VERB_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_TEMP1_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_TEMP2_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_TEMP3_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_TRAD_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_EXEMPL_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_V_IMAG_COL),
                                     cursor.getString(VerbsQuery.TAG_VAR1_COL));
                myverbs.add(page);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        VerbItem.setCount(cursor.getCount());

        Log.i(TAG, "c: "+ cursor.getCount());

        return myverbs.toArray(new VerbItem[myverbs.size()]);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}



      public interface VerbsQuery {
            int _TOKEN = 0x4;
        String TBN = MyTables.TABLE_VERBS;

            String[] PROJECTION = {
                    MyTables.ID_VERB_COL,
                    MyTables.ID_PAGE_COL,
                    MyTables.VERB_COL,
                    MyTables.TEMP1_COL,
                    MyTables.TEMP2_COL,
                    MyTables.TEMP3_COL,
                    MyTables.TRAD_COL,
                    MyTables.EXEMPL_COL,
                    MyTables.V_IMAG_COL,
                    MyTables.VAR1_COL,
            };

            int TAG_ID_VERB_COL = 0;
            int TAG_ID_PAGE_COL = 1;
            int TAG_VERB_COL = 2;
            int TAG_TEMP1_COL = 3;
            int TAG_TEMP2_COL = 4;
            int TAG_TEMP3_COL = 5;
            int TAG_TRAD_COL = 6;
            int TAG_EXEMPL_COL = 7;
            int TAG_V_IMAG_COL =8;
            int TAG_VAR1_COL =9;
        }



    }
```

i have try  that but allways java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public List<FeedPage> getAllPagess() {
         SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<FeedPage> feedpages = new ArrayList<FeedPage>();

        cursor = db.query(FeedContract.Entry.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] {FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_LINK, FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAG_LINK,FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_TEXT_ENTRY,FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_PUBLISHED},
                null, null, null, null, FeedContract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_PUBLISHED + " desc");

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            FeedPage feedpage = new FeedPage();

            feedpage.setId(cursor.getInt(TAG_ID));
            feedpage.setTitle(cursor.getString(TAG_TITLE).toString());
            feedpage.setLink(cursor.getString(TAG_LINK).toString());
            feedpage.setImaglink(cursor.getString(TAG_IMAG_LINK).toString());
            feedpage.setTextentry(cursor.getString(TAG_TEXT_ENTRY).toString());
            feedpage.setPublished(cursor.getLong(TAG_PUBLISHED));

            Log.d(TAG, "get comment = " + cursorToComment(cursor).toString());
            feedpages.add(feedpage);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return feedpages;
    }
```

Comment: Basically what you need is a Map of String to your Image Resources?

Comment: no im using une util imagloader i can get the image from them name

Comment: im looking to change all columns

Comment: i think i dont need to keep the imageResIds like ID i dont know for what that help !!! i meane if i will change the arraylist i dont need it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the files from the file name in your resources, something like this:

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromString(String myFaleName){
     Resources res = getResources();
     int resID = res.getIdentifier(myFaleName, "drawable", getPackageName());
     Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
     return drawable;
}
```

Comment: exactly but it not that the problem the query dont find any from db

Comment: if the query don't find nothing from DB the problem can be in your query :) , can you add the query on your question? (also the script that create the table), another thing... are you sure you have data on your database?

Comment: yes i can see the db is created and data is insered

Comment: there it s the source in the tuto

Comment: www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/android-tutorial-optimizing-phones-and-tablets-fragments[link]

Comment: im realy im lost ,if u have any solution for make it work with database

Comment: i need just one example